# How to convert an array of objects to an object in Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have this:

```
    [ { list: 
             [ [Object],
               [Object] ] },
      { head:
             [ [Object],
               [Object] ] }
    ]
```

And want to turn it into this:

```
    { list: 
                 [ [Object],
                   [Object] ],
      head:      [ [Object],
                   [Object] ]
    }
```

So an array of objects into an object. It would be great to achieve this with lodash.

Comment: I don't know anything about Java or lodash, but if you've done any research, it can really help if you share that, too! ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
_.reduce(array, function(memo, current) { return _.assign(memo, current) },  {})
```

Answer (score 27):

I think an even shorter solution would be:

```
Object.assign({}, ...array)
```

I know you asked for lodash, but it doesn't seem like you even need this way. Unless you want to use `_.extend`.

Comment: Perhaps my js is broken - but this just gets me the last element as an object.
This however had interesting result:
`Object.assign({},  ... rows.map(x=>{return {[x.name]:false}})  );  `
Which is the same below

Comment: Hey @terary, can you share what your object looks like?

Comment: {"list":[{"some":"object1"},{"some":"object2"}],"head":[{"some":"object3"},{"some":"object4"}]}
Node v12.19

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should've asked what does your original array look like? Or is the `list` property that you're trying to transform?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a shorter version:

```
_.transform(array, _.ary(_.extend, 2),  {});
```

The [transform()](https://lodash.com/docs#transform) function is like [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce), except it's not expecting you to return anything. Since [extend()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) is altering it's first argument, we can just pass it straight to `transform()`. It's wrapped in [ary()](https://lodash.com/docs#ary) to make sure it only gets 2 arguments passed to it.

Answer (score 10):

To build on @rcsole's great answer, this works well:

```
states = [{
  state: "NY",
  name: "New York",
}, {
  state: "AZ",
  name: "Arizona",
}]

statesObj = Object.assign({}, ...states.map(state => { 
  return { [state.state]: state.name } 
}))
```

### Result:

```
{
  AZ: "Arizona",
  NY: "New York",
}
```

### What's going on here?

Let's break this up into multiple pieces:

```
// Step 1: Transform from [{state: "Foo", name: "Bar"}, ...] to [{Foo: "Bar"}, ...]
mappedStates = states.map(state => { return { [state.state]: state.name } })

// Step 2: Merge all the objects in that array into a single new object
statesObj = Object.assign({}, ...mappedStates)
```

Step 1 uses `map` to iterate over every item in the array (every state object). `map` executes a function for every `state` object and returns a new object with the state as the key and the name as the value. We need to surround `state.state` in brackets because it's a dynamic value in an object literal.

Step 2 uses `Object.assign` to merge all the new state objects in the `mappedStates` array into a new object (the first parameter, `{}`). 
What are the three dots `...` for? That's the spread operator. It takes every element in the `mappedStates` array and turns them into direct arguments of the `Object.assign` method.

This example makes it clear:

```
Object.assign({}, ...mappedStates)
```

is the same as

```
Object.assign({}, {AZ: "Arizona"}, {NY: "New York"})
```

That's it!

Comment: Thanks for showing the use of square brackets creating object properties by name

Answer (score 1):

Use fromPairs on lodash 4. https://lodash.com/docs#fromPairs

`_.fromPairs([['fred', 30], ['barney', 40]]);`